Предлоги «в качестве», «в роли»
Я поехала в лагерь в качестве вожатой.
В качестве вожатой — какой член предложения?
То же самое и с предлогом «в роли»…
На сайтах про сравнительные обороты написано, что «как» можно заменить на «в качестве». Изменится ли роль оборота в предложении? Или это будет все тот же сравнительный оборот?
В мои обязанности как учителя русского языка входит…
А в данном случае «как учителя русского языка» чем будет? Приложением, сравнительным оборотом?


Нужно различать сравнительные обороты (значение like, художественное уподобление) от оборотов со значением тождества/приравнивания (значение as, в качестве). Они оба могут обособляться или нет, но решаются по разным правилам. В данном  случае это оборот со значением тождества.

Я поехала в лагерь в качестве вожатой.


В качестве — предлог. Соответственно, предложный оборот будет именной частью сказуемого.
Сравнить: Я поехала/была вожатой.  Я поехал/был вожатым в лагере. Согласование с подлежащим в роде и числе, управление со стороны сказуемого.
Оборот в качестве вожатой связан по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого он входит: поехала в качестве вожатой. (Такие конструкции называются трехчастными.)

В мои обязанности как учителя русского языка входит…

Сравнить: В мои обязанности (какие? кого?) учителя  входит…
Это  несогласованное определение, выраженное оборотом как учителя русского языка.

Материл по сравнительному обороту

Сравнительный оборот может быть приложением (определительное значение, обособляется) или обстоятельством образа действия (не  обособляется). Пример из Розенталя, пункт 4:
Она ускользнёт, как змея, порхнёт и умчится,
как птичка.  Автору важно было создать художественные образы путем, так сказать, чистого сравнения (подобно змее, подобно птичке, хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой, но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).
Сравнить: Как змея она ускользнет...  Обособления в начале предложения нет, это обстоятельство образа действия.
СЛОВАРИ
Русский орфографический словарь
в качестве (кого, чего)

Большой толковый словарь русского языка
В качестве кого-чего, в зн. предлога. В роли, на 
правах; в виде. Ему пришлось выступить в качестве 
переводчика. Использовать в качестве мебели.

